# Live Streaming in iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, video, http-live-streaming

I would like to implement live streaming in iOS app, i found some suggestions to convert and play already recorded videos, but i need to implement direct live streaming video from iPhone/Webcam to iOS App.

How to convert webcam/iPhone or any other recording video to .M3U8?, How to send this video to Server?

Please give me some suggestions and tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `MPMoviePlayerController`

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil]; 

[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[mp setFullscreen:YES];

[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];

[mp prepareToPlay];
[mp play];
```

Comment: It does not send video to Server.This code can just play video from that url.

Comment: @abhi1992 streaming is nothing but a video from server.

Comment: How to send the video recorded on an iphone to Server?This is his question.Not playing it from server.I also want the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

For youtube streams, you can use youtube-ios-player-helper lib.
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper